# print random data for each millisecond python

Tags: python, csv, printing, milliseconds

I want to print random data ranging from -1 to 1 in csv file for each millisecond using Python. I started with to print for each second and it worked. But, I am facing difficulty with printing random data for each millisecond. I want the timestamp to be in UNIX epoch format like "1476449030.55676" (for milliseconds, decimal point is not required)

```
tstep = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1)
tnext = datetime.datetime.now() + tstep
NumberOfReadings = 10;  # 10 values ( 1 value for 1 millisecond)
i = 0;
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'w+')
try: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)  
    while i < NumberOfReadings:
        writer.writerow((random.uniform(-1, 1), time.time()))
        tdiff = tnext - datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(float(tdiff.total_seconds()/1000))
        tnext = tnext + tstep
        i =i+1;
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: `time.sleep()` accepts argument in seconds, so you don't need to divide it by 1000. After fixing this, my output looks like this:

```
0.18153176446804853,1476466290.720721
-0.9331178681567136,1476466290.721784
-0.37142653326337327,1476466290.722779
0.1397040393287503,1476466290.723766
0.7126280853504974,1476466290.724768
-0.5367844384018245,1476466290.725762
0.44284645253432786,1476466290.726747
-0.2914685960956531,1476466290.727744
-0.40353712249981943,1476466290.728778
0.035369003158632895,1476466290.729771
```

Which is as good as it gets, given the precision of time.sleep and other time functions.

Here's a stripped down version, which outputs timestamps into stdout every second:

```
import time

tstep = 0.001
tnext = time.time() + tstep
NumberOfReadings = 10;  # 10 values ( 1 value for 1 millisecond)

for  i in range(NumberOfReadings):
    now = time.time()
    print(now)
    time.sleep(tnext - now)
    tnext += tstep
```

================================================

This is the problem:

```
float(tdiff.total_seconds()/1000)
```

You use integer division, and then convert result to float.
Instead, you need to use float division:

```
tdiff.total_seconds()/1000.0
```

Comment: @ t_tila: Thanks for your reply. I tried that too.  But I get the results like below: "-0.2985529200795216,1476453775.235422
0.3277184346531816,1476453775.235497
-0.651029174634272,1476453775.235593".   Here you can see that it prints 3 ( and more ) values for the same millisecond ("1476453775.235...") and not 1 value for 1 millisecond.  There is some other problem with the code..

Comment: I've ran your snippet and got one 2 values per line, a random float and a timestamp. The only changes I've made: fixed the float division, and opened file in `'w'` mode.

Comment: I agree. I get the same thing but it does not answer my question. Please check each timestamp values. Each line should have a timestamp which should have consecutive milliseconds... For e.g. I expect something like 1476453775.235... 1476453775.236..., 1476453775.237... and so on.. And not like 1476453775.235..., 1476453775.235..., etc... which have same millisecond.

Comment: @User1212 You're totally right! I've got it all messed up. I've updated my answer with the correct solution.

Comment: @ t_tia: I appreciate your efforts but I am not sure how you got that result. May be it depends on the system. I use ubuntu 14.04. I changed my code as you have mentioned but still I get like: "0.27738220024145366,1476468738.731939
-0.3371623815707159,1476468738.731995,..."..I get more samples for each millisecond :(

Comment: @ t_tia: I just remembered.. Actually, I use linux kernel version "4.2.0-22-lowlatency". May be my result is due to my low latency kernel!

Comment: @User1212 If there's a wild bug that makes time.sleep to not work on that specific kernel, then I'm out :D But to give it the last chance, I've added a code snippet in the answer. I wonder if you'll get the output too often again.
In my experience, 99% of problems like this happen because of some silly error in the code.

Comment: @ t_tia: Thank you.. It worked. One thing I find weird is that when I am printing in my terminal, I get like 1476685048.76, 1476685048.76,1476685048.77, 1476685048.77, etc. But when I write in the file, I get precision more than milliseconds like 1476685048.761178, 1476685048.762351, 1476685048.763301.. But you get the same millisecond precision in your terminal itself!

Comment: @User1212 I'm glad it worked! I also have floats with 2 digits precision inmy terminal. I used ipython to experiment with your code, which outputs floats with 6 digit precision. I don't know why it's different in case of terminal :/